# Как задать отступ у секции PHPWord?

Tags: php, phpword

есть секция

```
$sectionStyle = array('orientation' => 'portrait',
               'marginLeft' => '50px', //Левое поле равно 15 мм
               'marginRight' => '',
               'marginTop' => '10px',
               'borderTopColor' => 'C0C0C0'
        );
$section = $word->createSection($sectionStyle);
```

и картинка

```
$section->addImage('...../images/docImages/logo.png',[ 'width' => 182, 'height'=> 68]);
```

сколько бы пикселей я не указывал в $sectionStyle отступы всегда получаются одинаковые, примерно по 10мм .

Как управлять оступами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отступ задается не в пикселях, а в twip, сделай функцию примерно:

```
 /**
 * 1 твип равен 56.7 миллиметров
 *
 * @param int $millimeters
 * @return false|float
 */
private function convertMillimetersToTwips(int $millimeters) : float
{
    return floor($millimeters * 56.7);
}

и потом: 'marginLeft' => convertMillimetersToTwips(15)
```

Comment: пацаны ваще ребята